# One-Line Diagram Standardized Symbols Information

Tags: power, design, diagram, standard

Good day, people. I'm trying to get into *electrical substation design* and I'd like to know which **standard** sets the rules for substation **One-Line Diagram Symbols** .

Any ideas of where can I get that information?

I've already found *IEEE Standard C37.2-2008*, which is the **device number standard** of Directional Power Relays, Distance Relays, etc.

Regards,

F. Alvarez

Answer (score 1):

In the Australian world, we use AS 1102 *Graphical Symbols for Electrotechnical Documentation*, which is derived from [IEC 60617](http://std.iec.ch/iec60617) *Graphical Symbols for Diagrams*.

> The following areas are covered in the database:
>
> - Conductors and connecting devices
> - **Basic passive components**
> - Semiconductors and electron tubes
> - **Production and conversion of electrical energy** *(Includes generators and transformers)*
> - **Switchgear, controlgear and protective devices** *(Includes all kinds of switches, circuit breakers, disconnectors, and so forth)*
> - Measuring instruments, lamps and signalling devices
> - Telecommunications transmission, switching and peripheral equipment
> - Architectural and topographical installation plans and diagrams
> - Binary logic elements
> - Analogue and hybrid elements

This set of standards would apply in the IEC-speaking world, i.e. Europe, the UK and Commonwealth, etc. I couldn't say what standard is used by our American cousins.